# Cloudant sync and Cordova Client

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cloudant

We are developping a mobilefirst cordova application and we need to synchronise some (offline) data between the server and mobile devices. Cloundant seems an interesting choice but is there a JavaScript APIs for this? If not is this on a roadmap for the next version of mobilefirst platforme?

Regards,

Milan

Comment: You can use PouchDB with Cloudant: http://pouchdb.com and here https://docs.cloudant.com/libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

Roadmaps are not shared publically, but have you looked at IBM JSONStore for Hybrid applications (which include Cordova)? See here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/all-tutorials/

Comment: Yes we've looked at JSONStore, but Cloudant corresponds better to what we want. It seems that we could use pouchdb with in our MF cordova client (cloudant is supported by pouchdb), more over I found this link to a IBM presentation https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/offline-first/ .